# How do I get JSON output grouped by an attribute using XSL

Tags: json, xml, xslt

I have some input XML that looks like this:

```
 <list>
    <document>
       <content name="url">some_url_here</content>
       <content name="title">document title</content>
       <content name="state">CA</content>
       <content name="state">NY</content>  
   </document>
   <document>
      <content name="url">some_other_url_here</content>
      <content name="title">document2 title</content>
      <content name="title">duplicate title</content>
      <content name="state">OH</content>
      <content name="state">PA</content>  
      <content name="state">FL</content>  
  </document>
</list>
```

The end goal is to produce JSON that looks like this:

```
{
  "list": [
    {
      "contents": {
        "url": "some_url_here",
        "title": "document title",
        "state": [
          "CA",
          "NY"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "contents": {
        "url": "some_other_url_here",
        "title": "document2 title",
        "state": [
          "OH",
          "PA",
          "FL"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

This is what I've been trying to get working. I have a problem with the a rogue commas that is not valid json. I believe this is because the order of contents in XML can differ from the order in the XSL key so I can't reliably tell if there is a preceding item.

```
<xsl:template match="document">
    <xsl:variable name="doc" select="." />    
    <xsl:call-template name="indent" />
    <xsl:text>  "contents":{</xsl:text>

    <!-- get unique content names -->
    <xsl:for-each select="//content[generate-id() = generate-id(key('nameDistinct', @name)[1])]">
        <xsl:sort select="@name"/>
        <xsl:variable name="name" select="@name" />
        <xsl:variable name="count" select="count($doc/content[@name=$name])" />
        <xsl:variable name="contents" select="$doc/content[@name=$name]" />
        <xsl:variable name="preceeding" select="$doc/content[@name=$name]/preceding-sibling::content/text()!=''"/>

        <xsl:if test="position() > 1 and $preceeding > 0">
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>

        <xsl:if test="$count > 0">
            <xsl:call-template name="indent" />
        </xsl:if>

        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$count > 1">
                <!-- handle multiple contents -->            
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$count = 1">
                <!-- handle single content -->
            </xsl:when>
            </xsl:otherwise>                
        </xsl:choose>

    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

I'm struggling with the commas issue, but I think I may be approaching this entirely wrong. I'm also limited to XSLT 1.0.

Comment: You have a </xsl:otherwise> that is not matched by a starting <xsl:otherwise> and there is no template defined called indent.

Comment: I don't see how this is different than your previous question http://stackoverflow.com/q/40009895/317052

Comment: The template named indent is defined elsewhere. I'm having problems with this specific template so I've extracted it from other 1000 lines.